# Spring Tool SuiteでGradleProjectをリフレッシュした後、コンソールに色がつかなくなった

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

Spring Tool Suite(STS)を使って、Springの学習をしています。

途中でライブラリが不足していることに気づき、以下の操作を行いました。

- build.gradeにimplementationを１行追加
- Package Explorerから、プロジェクト名で右クリック > Gradle > Reflesh Gradle Project
- リフレッシュ完了後、プロジェクトを起動

すると、下図のように文字がすべて白黒になりました。
[image: コンソール]

単純な文字化けかと思いフォントをいろいろ変えてみましたが、改善していません。
コンソールに色を戻す方法はありますでしょうか。

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation' //追加
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

STS にデフォルトでインストールされているプラグイン [ANSI Escape in Console](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ansi-escape-console) が該当機能を担っています。

原因としては、意図せず次の状態のいずれかになってしまっていることが考えられます:

- プラグインをアンインストールした
- プラグインの機能を無効化した

**Window > Preference** メニューで表示される設定ダイアログで **Ansi Console** の設定を確認してみてください。
(プラグインをアンインストールしている場合であれば、この設定項目自体が存在しないと思います)

[image: Ansi Console 設定]